# How is this code synchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

```
function foo(cb) {
  if (!someAuditCondition) {
    return cb(new Error(...));   // <- This is NOT asynchronous, but the rest of the function is!
  }

  doSomeAsynAction(function (err, data) {
    if (err) { return cb(err); }
    cb(data);
  });
}
```

how is that part synchronous . and also how processing that cb in process.nextTick() will make it asynchronous.

Comment: Is it actually that hard to format and indent your code properly?

Comment: Where is the rest of the function? Why do you think it's asynchronous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is synchronous cause you are not using any asynchronous functions at all, even it is a callback you are just passing the response to the next function call, callbacks are not asynchronous by nature, asynchronous functions do them that way.

```
function foo(cb) {
  if (!someAuditCondition) {
    return process.nextTick(() => {
      cb(new Error('err'));
    });
  };
}


function foo(cb) {
  if (!someAuditCondition) {
    return setImmediate(() => {
      cb(new Error('err'));
    });
  };
}

function foo(cb) {
  if (!someAuditCondition) {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      cb(new Error('err'));
    }, 0);
  };
}
```

**`process.nextTick`** - will put your callback in the top of the `event loop  queue` what that means, is that it will take your function from the main execution thread, and put it on top of `libuv` message queue, and then `libuv` will check after each tick if there are any sync functions to be executed in the stack, if there are none, then it will pop your callback;

**`setImmediate`** - will put it in the queue, but this not always can be first;

**`setTimeout(cb, 0)`** - is practically the same thing as `setImmediate`

When you use an asynchronous function you are sending your callback in os thread which will be transported back to the main execution thread by `libuv`. This means `asynchronous` in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

The fact of calling callback in function is not asynchronous. I am pretty sure you wrote the code like this:

```
function B () {
  return 1; 
}

function A () { 
  var b = B();
  ...
}
```

If you think, it is no different from:

```
function A(B) {
  var b = B()
}
```

Where `B` can be any function, including anonymous function (which your callback is).